# Include js and css files from node_modules into a static html page

Tags: css, node.js, npm

My dev server is running on node live-server. My prod will be a LAMP server.

I have `normalize.css` inside my node_modules server.
In my `index.html` I have

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

I don't want files linked to `node_modules` directory.

I want something like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
```

Is this doable? I have lot of other css and js files like this.

**Update 1**

Let me clarify, this app is not a node app nor a php app, It has only html, css and js files. Everything runs on client side, But.. we want to leverage the latest client side dev tools for JS and CSS and upload the final build to prod server.

Comment: A LAMP server?? Why on earth would (and _could_) a PHP server be used to run a Node app?

Comment: @JeremyThille only dev is a node server to make use of new JS architecture and packages. Prod is a Lamp server, its a enterprise decision.

Comment: But... You are aware that PHP is a language, and Javascript another language, that Node is a server, Apache another server, right? They are _completely_ different technologies. Competitors. Running a Node app with PHP/Apache doesn't make sense. So, good luck with this "enterprise decision" :)

Comment: Typically you’d use a build tool to copy things from node_modules into some assets folder and refer to that. You can also configure Apache to serve static files from node_modules, though.

Comment: @JeremyThille Let me clarify, this app is not a node app nor a php app, It has only html, css and js files. Everything runs on client side, But.. we want to leverage the latest client side dev tools for JS and CSS and upload the final build to prod server.

Comment: So why did you use the `node.js` and `npm` tags?

Comment: because dev is done in nodejs + liveserver, also we could use npm and other features during build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of possible solutions. I can suggest using a task runner(gulp) which will copy these static files to a public directory like `dist/assets`.

**Install gulp on your machine**

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

**Create a `gulpfile.js` file in your root directory with following code.**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src('/node_modules/normalize.css')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets'));
});
```

**Run gulp**

```
gulp
```

**Update your `index.html` as below**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/assets/normalize.css">
```

Please go through the documentation of [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) for more information

You can also try [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Webpack` for bundling, which would copy css resources to the dist and replace references to it. It doesn't support html files as entry points though, so you'd need to work around that by probably using `html-webpack-plugin`.

anyway, as was mentioned by others - server decisions are weird.